# Error when mkdir in multi threads in python

Tags: python, runtime-error, mkdir

I have code in multi threads to create folder if not exists

```
if not os.path.exists(folder): os.makedirs(folder)
```

I got error like this

```
The folder cannot be created since a file already exists with the same path
```

I am not sure what can I do for this error, do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you have multiple threads trying to create the same folder? The problem is that thread 1 might create the folder between the time thread 2 checks if it exists and then tries to create it.

Comment: you need to implement mutual exclusion between the threads, so that the test and creation are performed atomically.

Comment: I am afraid performance if I use Mutual. In fact, I check and create folder in main thread at first, but I don't want to create folder if no any image download so that I move that function to just before save in threads, is there any way to not affect performance and do what I need?

Comment: Unless you're calling this code frequently, don't worry about the performance. Get it right first, then worry about performance if it's a bottleneck.

Comment: You could just try to create the directory, and ignore the error if it already exists. Then whichever thread gets here first will create it.

Comment: Yeah, now I do it like you said, the code will do what I need, I just want to avoid warning message as I am a perfectionism...

Comment: If you're using Python 3, just pass the `exist_ok` argument as `True` and it won't complain of an existing directory. Read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Great! that is what I need! Answer me!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs). If you don't care whether the directory already existed, just that it does when you're done, just call:

```
os.makedirs(folder, exist_ok=True)
```

Don't even check for the existence of the directory with `exists` (subject to race conditions), just call `os.makedirs` with `exist_ok=True` and it will create it if it doesn't exist and do nothing if it already exists.

This requires Python 3.2 or higher, but if you're on an earlier Python, you can achieve the same silent ignore with exception handling:

```
import errno

try:
    os.makedirs(folder)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise  # Reraise if failed for reasons other than existing already
```

Comment: Great! This is what I need!

Comment: I just want to add that this is also true for `pathlib.Path`:
`dest.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)`

Comment: It appears to not be the case. https://bugs.python.org/issue21082#msg215346 points out exist_ok is not thread-safe.

Comment: Do you know if it is already fixed? @Leedehai

Comment: @AntonioBri: The race Leedehai refers to appears to only be possible if multiple threads are both creating *and* removing/renaming the directory in question. As long as you're only creating the directory, the race doesn't occur. The code has changed since then, but only insofar as it simplified the check on `OSError` to just `if not exist_ok or not path.isdir(name): raise`, so if multiple threads are both creating the directory and removing/renaming it, then a race remains possible.